# How to go backward and upwards through buttons - canvas tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

So i am doing this exercise with python tkinter, where i have this canvas displaying images and i am storing its directories in a list and in a listbox. I have all the other things figured out, but i have no idea on how to know which index (image/directory) is being displayed on the canvas. so how would the functions that i need to assign to those buttons ('<' and '>') go?
I need to know which index is being displayed on the canvas and then just -1 on that index, right? But i wasn't taught yet and to know/get the image that is currently on the canvas. Thank you so much!

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIdZo.jpg)

```
class Application:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        pass


window=Tk() 
Application(window) 
#window.geometry("300x200")
window.title("Hello Python")
window.configure(bg= "white")
window.resizable(0,0) 
window.title('ToDoList')

screenWidth = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = window.winfo_screenheight()

appWidth =600 #my app width
appHeight = 500 #my app height

x = (screenWidth/2) - (appWidth/2)
y = (screenHeight/2) - (appHeight/2)
window.geometry(f'{appWidth}x{appHeight}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')

def upwards():
    ????????????
def backwards():
    ???????????

def lista_images():
    
    lista= []
    lista.clear() 
    cont = lb.size()
    for i in range(cont):
        ficheiro = lb.get(i)
        imagem = ficheiro
        lista.append(imagem)
    return lista



def selecionar():
    global filename, lista
    global img_canvas, ctnImage, img_selecionada
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Selecione a sua imagem de perfil', initialdir='Ficha 15\imagens', 
    filetypes=(('png files', '*.png'), ('gif files', '*.gif'),))

    img_canvas = PhotoImage(file = filename)
    lb.insert(END, filename)
    #change the image on canvas
    #se a lista estiver vazia, a imagem a ser apresentada no canvas será a primeira inserida, se não será a última. usar o método size da lbox
    ctnImage.itemconfig(img_selecionada,image=img_canvas,)
    lista = lista_images()
    print(lista)


#LISTBOX
lb = Listbox(window, width=100, height=10, selectmode="multiple")
lb.place(x=10, y=320)

#IMAGE
ctnImage = Canvas(window, width=400, height=280, bd = 2, relief="sunken")
ctnImage.place(x=180, y=20)
img = PhotoImage(file = '')
img_selecionada = ctnImage.create_image(10,10, anchor="nw", image= img,)

#BUTTONS
btn_selecionar = Button(window, text="Selecionar imagem",fg = "blue", height=2, width=15,relief="raised", justify='center',command=selecionar)
btn_selecionar.place(x = 20, y=25)

btn_anterior = Button(window, text="<",fg = "blue", height=2, width=15,relief="raised", justify='center',command=backwards )
btn_anterior.place(x = 20, y=185)

btn_seguinte = Button(window, text=">",fg = "blue", height=2, width=15,relief="raised", justify='center',command=upwards )
btn_seguinte.place(x = 20, y=225)


window.mainloop() #event listening loop
```

Comment: Do you store all the paths to images in list, and want to change image to upward image and downward image when clicking on right and left button?

Answer (score 0):

You can store current image in `current_image` and render image according to it, like this: 
Your upward function will look like this:

```
def upwards():
    global current_image, lista, img_canvas, img_selecionada
    index = lista.index(current_image)
    img_canvas = PhotoImage(file=lista[index-1])
    current_image = lista[index-1]
    ctnImage.itemconfig(img_selecionada, image=img_canvas,)
```

Backward Function:

```
def backwards():
    global current_image, lista, img_canvas, img_selecionada
    index = lista.index(current_image)
    if index + 1 <= len(lista):
        img_canvas = PhotoImage(file=lista[index+1])
        current_image = lista[index-1]
    else:
        img_canvas = PhotoImage(file=lista[0])
        current_image = lista[0]

    ctnImage.itemconfig(img_selecionada, image=img_canvas,)
```

You need to update your `selectionar` function like this:

```
def selecionar():
    global filename, lista
    global img_canvas, ctnImage, img_selecionada, current_image
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Selecione a sua imagem de perfil', initialdir='Ficha 15\imagens', filetypes=(('png files', '*.png'), ('gif files', '*.gif'),))

    current_image = filename

    img_canvas = PhotoImage(file=filename)
    lb.insert(END, filename)
    ctnImage.itemconfig(img_selecionada, image=img_canvas,)
    lista = lista_images()
    print(lista)
```

And make sure to declare `current_image` in global scope. 
I hope this solves your problem.